# Get sum of time from different mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible and if yes, how?
to get total sum of time from 2 or more tables like this:

**table1**

```
id, racer_nr, total_time_spend
1, 315 , 03:01:40
1, 312 , 06:01:40
1, 313 , 10:01:40
```

**table2**

```
id, racer_nr, total_time_spend
1, 315 , 07:01:40
1, 312 , 15:15:00
1, 313 , 10:01:40
```

need to get sum of total_time_spend of each `racer_nr` from all the tables.
Have 5 of them atleast, just gave you 2 for simplier

Comment: Just 1 entry per racer_nr per table?

Comment: Union the two tables, and then use `SUM` and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Why do you have the same schema in multiple tables? You probably should combine these all into a single table, with an additional column that contains whatever distinguishes them.

Comment: Yes.. only one entry per racer_nr per table
:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
drop table if exists t,t2;

create table t(id int, racer_nr int, total_time_spend time);
insert into t values
(1, 315 , '03:01:40'),
(1, 312 , '06:01:40'),
(1, 313 , '10:01:40');
create table t2(id int, racer_nr int, total_time_spend time);
insert into t2 values
(1, 315 , '07:01:40'),
(1, 312 , '15:15:00'),
(1, 313 , '10:01:40');



select t.racer_nr, sec_to_time(sum(spendsecs))
from
(
select t.racer_nr , time_to_sec(total_time_spend) spendsecs
from t 
union all
select t.racer_nr , time_to_sec(total_time_spend) spendsecs
from t2 t
) t
group by racer_nr

+----------+-----------------------------+
| racer_nr | sec_to_time(sum(spendsecs)) |
+----------+-----------------------------+
|      312 | 21:16:40                    |
|      313 | 10:01:40                    |
|      315 | 10:03:20                    |
+----------+-----------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Read up on date time functions here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Yes! your answer is working perfectly.. :) 
but maybe you could help me little bit more
I have in the same tables more columns like arrive_time, and I would like to get each table.arrive_time (arrive1, arrive2) to return values also.. :)

Comment: Please raise as a new question with an expansion on what you have and what you want.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48721312/get-sum-of-times-from-different-tables-with-other-columns here it is ;)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will solve your problem.

```
SELEC SUM(table1.total_time_spend+ table2.total_time_spend) Total 
From table1, table2 
WHERE table1.racer_nr = table2.racer_nr 
group by table1.racer_nr 
order by Total
```