# Get sum of times from different tables with other columns

Tags: php, mysql

Have few tables like this:

```
id   racer_nr  start_time`           arrive_time           spent_time
1    313       2018-02-04 10:00:00   2018-02-04 18:57:00   08:57:00
2    135       2018-02-04 10:00:00   2018-02-04 18:59:20   08:59:20
3    55        2018-02-04 10:00:00   2018-02-04 18:59:50   08:59:50
4    315       2018-02-04 10:00:00   2018-02-04 20:01:40   10:01:40
```

different table different day. 
need to get total `spent_time` from all the tables of each racer and i'm getting that with query like this:

```
SELECT `race_day_1`.`racer_nr`, 
    sec_to_time(sum(spendsecs)) AS total_time_spent
    FROM
    (
        SELECT `race_day_1`.`racer_nr` , time_to_sec(`spent_time`) spendsecs
        FROM `race_day_1`

        UNION ALL
        SELECT `race_day_1`.`racer_nr` , time_to_sec(`spent_time`) spendsecs
        FROM `race_day_2` `race_day_1`

        UNION ALL
        SELECT `race_day_1`.`racer_nr` , time_to_sec(`spent_time`) spendsecs
        FROM `race_day_3` `race_day_1`

        UNION ALL
        SELECT `race_day_1`.`racer_nr` , time_to_sec(`spent_time`) spendsecs
        FROM `race_day_4` `race_day_1`

        UNION ALL
        SELECT `race_day_1`.`racer_nr` , time_to_sec(`spent_time`) spendsecs
        FROM `race_day_5` `race_day_1`
    ) `race_day_5`
GROUP BY `racer_nr`
```

which I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48720352/get-sum-of-time-from-different-mysql-tables#answer-48720498)

But I really would like to get each table (day) `start_time` and `arrive_time` and `spent_time` also.. is it possible to do that in the same query? if yes - how?

Comment: Fix your schema. You should not have separate tables for each race day.

Comment: why you don't just only add `start_time, arrive_time` in each `SELECT ...` part ?